# SES refuses to send email from own domain even though domain and email address are verified + no sandbox

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have added my own domain (a namecheap domain) to AWS SES and created the CNAME records at namecheap about a week ago to use Easy DKIM. I added an email address to SES within this domain, say myemail@example.com, example.com being the aforementioned domain. Both were successfully verified by AWS as it can be seen by the green checkmark (and the region is correct):
[image: checkmark]

However, when I want to send an email from this domain via boto3, I get a MessageRejected error:

```
An error occurred (MessageRejected) when calling the SendEmail operation: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region MyRegion: arn:aws:ses:MyRegion:MyAWSAccount:identity/myemail@example.com.
```

The region is correct and my account is not in the sandbox anymore. It works to send from an existing email address outside of the domain, for example my gmail email address.

How can I send emails from my own domain?

Here is the relevant code:

```py
ses_client = boto3.client("ses")

source_email_address = "myemail@example.com"
destination_email_address = "example_email_address@gmail.com"

response = ses_client.send_email(
    Source=source_email_address,
    Destination={
        "ToAddresses": [
            destination_email_address,
        ],
    },
    Message={
        "Subject": {"Data": subject, "Charset": "utf-8"},
        "Body": {
            "Text": {"Data": email_txt, "Charset": "utf-8"},
        },
    },
    SourceArn=f"arn:aws:ses:MyRegion:MyAWSAccount:identity/{source_email_address}",
    ReturnPathArn=f"arn:aws:ses:MyRegion:MyAWSAccount:identity/{source_email_address}",
)
```

Comment: So, you have verified the "test@example.com" address and the "example.com" domain in SES and now you try to send an email with a sender of "somethingelse@example.com" which fails. Is that correct?

Comment: I try to send from test@example.com. The other example email address was just to show that it works for other email addresses. I'll make the post clearer.

Comment: You give a `ReturnPathArn` but don't specify a `ReturnPath`. That could be a problem ... And you could also try using just the domain in the `...Arn` properties instead of the email addresses, and also explicitely specify the region when initializing the boto3 client, like in the example in the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/sending-authorization-delegate-sender-tasks-email.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It indeed works when I use the domain's arn (the other suggestions did not help). Happy to accept your answer if you post it.